# InstanceOf keyword doesn't working in java applet

Tags: java, applet, keyword, instanceof

can someone please tell mo why this code generating false rather then to generate true.... Is there any fault in the code.. I am trying to use `instanceof` keyword??

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class CheckInstanceOf extends java.applet.Applet
{
      TextField print;

      public void init()
      {
          print=new TextField(check_forInstance());
          add(print);
      }

      public String check_forInstance()
      {

          if(print instanceof TextField)
          {
              return "true";
          }
          else
          {
              return "false";
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: `(null instanceof TextField) == false`

Comment: Is `init()` actually being called? (1) Don't work with applets until you already have a thorough understanding of Java, and (2) the point of of using `import` is so that you don't have to use the full name of a class.

Comment: ohoo..... yes i forgot..null reference.. thank you very much..

Comment: @chrylis try to compile and run the code its successfully running...

Comment: Compile and run *how*?

Comment: do you have any idea about programming languages @chrylis... (1)Do not comment without any proper knowledge of the question being asked and (2) the point of your comment is useless and then asking "Compile and run how?"....

Answer (score 1):

You are actually making the `instanceof` test before actually creating it. You are doing the test before the `init()` method is called, so `print` should be `null`.

Thus, as @user3580294 said, `(null instanceof TextField) == false`.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken you are checking if print is a textField before initializing the object. You should probably redesign this so it doesn't need instanceOf but try creating`print = new TextField();` and then setting true or false afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

That's why `print` is `null` and null is not instance of TextField.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion : don't make use of instanceOf operator.
[read this blog for reference](https://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/when-polymorphism-fails)